# how to make dropdown select for tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make the tabs to dropdown in mobile view like [this](http://zozoui.com/tabs/deep-linking/#themes)? I know that is a PlugIn but is there a way to do like this plugin? this is what i have as of now [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krj4Lvv8/).

HTML:

```
<div id="tabbed-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Popular Upload</a></li>
    <li><a>Recent Upload</a></li>
    <li><a>Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabbed-content">
    <div>Popular Upload Content</div>
    <div>Recent Upload Content</div>
    <div>Gallery Content</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tabbed-nav {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: red;
}

#tabbed-content {
  background: green;
}
```

I've been searching how to do like that but can't find it. I hope i can answer here.

Comment: You have to use Jquery

Comment: It could be done with CSS only

Comment: Yeah but how sir? any suggest or sample code? its my first time doing something like this i really need help